# Reflexive calls go wrong because of getClass()

Tags: java, introspection, getmethod

I'm facing something that I don't think is solvable, but it's worth a try.
Assume you have the following classes :

```
package a;

public class A
{
    protected A() {}

    public static void staticMethod(A a) {
        // ...
    }
}

public class B extends A
{
    public B() {}
}
```

So you can instantiate `B` from other packages, but not `A`. Now assume you want to use `Class.getMethod`, only you're using some kind of reflexivity framework that goes something like :

```
public Object callStaticMethod(Class c, String methodname, Object[] args)
{
    Class[] signature = new Class[args.length];
    for (i = 0 ; i < args.length ; ++i) {
        signature[i] = args.getClass();
    }
    Method m = c.getMethod("methodname", signature);
    return m.invoke(null, args)
}
```

This method is given to me as-is, and sadly I can not improve it.
Now you may want to call the method like this :

```
package b;

B b;
callStaticMethod(A.class, "staticMethod", b);
```

...Except that will not work, because the signature generated (based on `getClass()` results will be `{B.class}`, and there is no method called `staticMethod` in `A` which takes a `B` as parameter.

Would any of you know about that ?

**BONUS** : As an additional challenge, is there a way, with this method, to call `staticMethod` with a null parameter (which may also be perfectly valid, semantically)? I personally haven't found a way to.

Comment: Tell the person who wrote the framework that it's broken, because it doesn't follow the method resolution process described in the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/expressions.html#15.12.2).

Comment: I just noticed that the framework's method is an instance method. Do you have any ability to override the framework class?

Comment: Sadly, I can't either. I'll just wait for a few more days, and then I'll close this question, the correct answer being: blame original author :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you'd have to do is use something like [`Class.getMethods`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethods%28%29), then check each candidate method for suitability. You may wish to consider:

- Boxing (so `long.class` would be valid for a `Long` value in `args`)
- Varargs (so if you have two `String` arguments, you *may* want to consider that valid for a method of `foo(String... args)`)
- Null compatibility (basically with any class-type parameter)
- Assignment compatibility (probably via `Class.isAssignableFrom`)
- Generics (this will almost certainly prove horrible)

If there are multiple applicable candidate methods, you *may* want to consider emulating the Java overloading rules - but I'd probably avoid it and go bang if you can :)

Comment: The thing is: `callStaticMethod` is provided by a framework, and I have no control over it. All I can do is try my best to make do with it :( I'll make it clearer in my question.